# Variable name and dependent variable

Tags: maxima

I'm trying to define dependent variables in `maxima` as follows:

```
depends(V[r],[r,\theta,z]);depends(v[%theta],[r,\theta,z]);depends(v[z],[r,\theta,z]);
```

And it throws me this error

> depends: argument must be a symbol; found: Vr

I know that this means that I should not use variable name as dependent variable. But that is what exactly I need(to use variable name as dependent variable as well, as this will make it easy for me to `Latex` the equations).

Also, I have used vectors(V) indexed at p, theta, zero to denote a variable with subscript. This is a work around.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: If you write `depends(V, foo)` then any subscripted `V` such as `V[r]` also depends on `foo`. Maybe this is enough for you. However if you want `V[r]` to depend on `foo` but some other subscript, say `V[s]` to not depend on `foo`, then that can't be expressed in this way.

Comment: @RobertDodier Is there any way to declare variable with a subscript without declaring it as an array?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about declaring it as an array. If you just want to use `r` as a subscript for `V`, you just write `V[r]`.

Comment: @RobertDodier : Now I got what you said. Thanks! :)